# Django : How to differentiate post requests from different pages that are coming to the same page?

Tags: python, django, post, django-views, http-post

I have two pages both containing form. However both the pages are sending post request to the same page. How do I differentiate which page has sent the request.

**dummy.html**(first page)

```
<form action="/nda" method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="I Agree"  target="_blank">I Agree</button>

        <button onclick="window.open('/greeting')" target="_blank"> I Disagree </button></br>
</form>
```

This page redirects to nda page.

**nda.html**(second page)

This page also redirects to the same page.

```
<form action="/nda"  method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="I Agree" target="_self">I Agree</button>
    <button onclick="window.open('/greeting')" target="_self"> I Disagree </button></br>
</form>
```

My question is, how do I differentiate in my view that from which page it was coming from the page dummy or the same page that was nda.

**views.py**

```
def nda(request):
    if request.method=='POST' :
        # if this is from dummy I want to do this
        return render(request,'mainapp/nda.html',{'user':email.split('@')[0]})

    if request.method=='POST' :
        # if this is from same page that is nda I want to do this
        return render(request,'mainapp/home.html')
```

I am unable to figure out, how do I handle both cases differently

Comment: Why not have them go to two different views?

Comment: in that case, I wouldn't have asked this question

Comment: (1) If you are writing both ends of your app, why would you not use a normal parameter like... `page_origin`? (2) You might have thought of `views.py` as common code for both, and just came across the first counterexample, so maybe design is not correct...? (it sounds like you are going to have to refactor in the near future, you might as well do it now and right from the beginning). As already suggested by Kent. You seem too sure about your design, this is a common mistake. Not duplicating some code in this cases can be expensive. Give it a second thought.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Apologies if that was a dumb suggestion but to me this feels like a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why can't you have them go to two views? For example, are you trying to not duplicate code in your view?

Comment: @KentShikama since both are redirecting to the same page how do I create separate views for them

Comment: By using action="/nda" on both you're forcing them to go to POST to the same URL and thus they get directed to the same view.

Comment: Usually you would just leave action="" (blank) so that they would POST to the URL the page was originally fetched from, which would be different for both pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question properly,you can use the name attribute in your submit button

```
<button type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit" value="I Agree"  target="_blank">I Agree</button

<button type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit" value="I Agree"  target="_blank">I Agree</button
```

And in the views

```
def nda(request):
    if request.method=='POST' and 'submit1' in request.POST :
        # do something
        return render(request,'mainapp/nda.html',{'user':email.split('@')[0]})

    elif request.method=='POST' and 'submit2' in request.POST:
        #do something else
        ...
```

Answer (score -2):

How it works ?
    You click on the submit button and the server is accessing ..
    A button with type submit follows the "action" path specified in the form tag
    That is, so that you have a request for different pages, you need to create an additional url, views and html

Example:

one_html.html

```
<form action="{% url your_app:name1 %}" method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="I Agree"  target="_blank">I Agree</button>

        <button onclick="window.open('/greeting')" target="_blank"> I Disagree </button></br>
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^' + app_name + 'some_path', views_one, name='name1'),
```

views.py:

```
def views_one(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        # do something
```

Exapmle:

two_html.html

```
<form action="{% url your_app:name2 %}" method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="I Agree"  target="_blank">I Agree</button>

        <button onclick="window.open('/greeting')" target="_blank"> I Disagree </button></br>
</form>
```

urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^' + app_name + 'some_path', views_two, name='name2'),
```

views.py:

```
def views_two(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        # do something
```

The difference is that the action points to a different url and thus will be called different views

Comment: You know that you can be banned from answering further 1. This is wrong answer 2. Formatting is not correct 3. This answer even if right is not for Django 2+

Comment: Sorry, I did not format the text properly, so nothing is clear